# the usage of the phrase "their shoulders"

Tags: word-usage

> The big breakers came in slowly; their shoulders growing tall and green.

I'd like to know whether "their shoulders" in this sentence is used correctly.
Does the word "green" mean "full of energy"?

Comment: What is the source of this sentence?  Can you give more context?

Comment: These sentences are taken from the story "Dreams Do Come True" by Jim Bishop.

Comment: And the context?  I suspect here that *breakers* are ocean waves, and that *shoulders* means "a wider part of the wave just below the very top", analogous to the shoulders on the human body.  But without context I cannot be sure.

Comment: @NateEldredge: You got it right, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a metaphor.

A wave coming ashore rises slowly and before it breaks (crushes down), it might seem to somebody a hunched giant whose neck is bent down, and only the shoulders and the back are visible.  The rising of the wave is like growing of that hunched-over giant, with the shoulders slowly getting higher/taller and the water turning a bit more translucent on the top making the "shoulders" turn green.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.  Not a metaphor, the reference to a shoulder is simply a less common use of the word.

The definition of shoulder in Merriam-Webster (one of the most accepted English Dictionaries) includes this:  an area adjacent to or along the edge of a higher, more prominent, or more important part [such as] the part of a hill or mountain near the top.

Using this definition, the shoulder of a wave is simply the portion near the top.

Comment: You should probably [edit] to add the link if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

"Shoulder" is used to refer to a portion near the crest of the wave, but lower.  It's a part which hasn't broken yet.  (Breaking is when the water comes apart and appears white.)

Here's a [link](http://www.surfscience.com/ask-a-scientist?task=view&id=141) and here's [another](http://www.thesurfingsite.com/Surf-Slang.html).  The second notes that a shoulder may also be called a corner in surfing jargon.

http://www.alohasurfguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Wave-Anatomy-1-1024x594.jpg[image]